# Python pytest unittest.TextTestRunner doesn't run specific suites

Tags: python, pytest

I have a problem with running test suites.
I'm using pytest for fixtures and test ordering and unittests for running suites. All test classes have parameter (unittest.TestCase)

The file I execute from in the same directory (folder/package) where tests are.  I execute TestSuite with command, `pytest tests/test_suit.py`.  Here is test_suit.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TextTestRunner
from unittest import TestLoader

from tests.home_page.login_test import LoginTest
from tests.cloud.cloud_test import CloudTest

tc1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(CloudTest)
tc2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginTest)

smokeTest = unittest.TestSuite([tc1])

unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(smokeTest)
```

The problem is, it executes all TestCases, even if I put just one. Looks like it collects all classes where I have argument `(unittest.TestCase)` and doesn't pick up correct TestSuite.

It does not matter if I do `smokeTest = unittest.TestSuite([tc1])` or `smokeTest = unittest.TestSuite([tc2, tc1])`, it still runs all TestCases.

Comment: Why are you doing this? The whole point of using tools like py.test and nose is to let *them* collect and run the tests. You should *not* need to define `TestSuite` at all. If you only want to run the `LoginTest` you can specify so on the command line, or using the decorators provided to skip the other tests.

Comment: Well I have bunch of testsuitess like smoke, functional, regression and the all have their own sets of testcases.

Comment: So? If you want to run the smoke tests use `pytest tests/test_smoke.py`, or `pytest tests/smoke_tests` if it is a directory. If you group your tests correctly in files/directories you shouldn't have to do nothing to collect the tests to run, you just specify the directory/file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my non-answer.  Having checked the [pytest documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html) and found paragraphs like (emphasis added),

> Note that this is meant as a **provisional** way of running your test code
>   **until you fully convert** to pytest-style tests. To fully take advantage
>   of fixtures, parametrization and hooks you should convert (tools like
>   unittest2pytest are helpful). Also, not all 3rd party pluging are
>   expected to work best with unittest.TestCase style tests.

do you have a reasonable expectation that you should be able to call pytest on a unittest-style test runner?

Looking at [pytest's own test for unittest compatibility](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/0b94c43baccf02268eb432eef475480a2a5749ae/testing/test_unittest.py), and their [unittest.py module](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/3d9c5cf19fa821c785866133d3417215cde2bc55/_pytest/unittest.py) itself, I see no support or validation of unittest-style TestSuites, which your test_suite.py is dependent on, and which forms the basis for this question.  I only see support for that which they document they support, unittest.TestCase.

**pytest does the *wrong* thing**

```
so zyoung$ pytest tests/test_suit.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.0.6, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/zyoung/so, inifile: 
collected 2 items 

tests/test_suit.py ..

=========================== 2 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

**python/unittest does the *correct* thing**

```
so zyoung$ python tests/test_suit.py 
test (cloud.cloud_test.CloudTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```